# Only one executor is running in spark. only master is working but no one

Tags: java, apache-spark

**As i have 10 nodes in cluster, each node consists of 2 cores, altogether there are 20 cores with me. I have set num-executors = 20. But only one master computer is working now. where are other 18 cores ?**

*Below are the list images showing the UI view of 
performance:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have the spark-submit code as below :

```
./bin/spark-submit --class Package.Class --master spark://master-url:7077 --deploy-mode client --num-executors 20  /home/ec2-user/AWS.jar
```

**what can i do to improve the performance so that every computer will together and it will have required number of stages or jobs ?**

Comment: What type of file are you reading? If this file is a Parquet compressed this will be only one worker.

Comment: I have .gz compressed file.

Comment: I am using this line to read the file-->    sparkSession.read().format("json").load(path);

Comment: Well maybe that is the reason. Try to use a `coalese` or `repartition` function after you load the file. Put the number of workers you have. This maybe will solve your problem

Comment: i have tried  using this one but same performance , no improvement --> sparkSession.read().format("json").load(profile).repartition(sc.defaultMinPartitions() * 3);

Comment: Humm now we maybe have a problem. Well now we have a problem. Check here if you can find anything useful: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-partitions.html#repartitioning

Comment: Not solved . anyone can help me ?

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue